# Refactoring code in constructor or stub/shim it out?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a method I'm testing. The constructor for this method calls to its base class constructor and then in its base class constructor it sets a few members and then executes a method to fetch data from a db then sets some of the database values to more members (all done in the constructor).

Should I, in order to test my original method, remove the call to the database in the constructor and refactor it so it just sets some members, then I can easily run the constructor in my test and stub out any interfaces that are being passed in (in this case 1) or should I try to shim out the method in the contructor that makes the database call??

```
    // method under test
    public override DateTime ResolveDate(ISeries comparisonSeries, DateTime targetDate)
    {
        switch (comparisonSeries.Key)
        {
            case SeriesKey.SomeKey1:
            case SeriesKey.SomeKey2:
            case SeriesKey.SomeKey3:
            case SeriesKey.SomeKey4:
            case SeriesKey.SomeKey5:
                return DateHelper.PreviousOrCurrentQuarterEnd(targetDate);
            default:
                break;
        }

        return base.ResolveDate(comparisonSeries, targetDate);
    }
// constructor
    public ReportForm(SeriesKey key, IAppCache cache)
        : base(key, cache)
    {
        //sets some base members here.
    }

 // base class that the constructor calls
 public abstract class SeriesBase : ISeries
{
    #region variables

    protected IAppCache clientCache;
    // other members below

        // base constructor
public SeriesBase(SeriesKey key, IAppCache cache)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.clientCache = cache;
        this.infoPack = new SeriesInfo();
        this.InitalizeSeries();
    }
private void InitalizeSeries()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> qInfoSQL = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        qInfoSQL.Add("@SeriesID", this.key.ToIntString());

        DBServiceResult result = this.clientCache.DBService.FetchFromDB("spSeriesInit", CommandType.StoredProcedure, qInfoSQL);

        if (result.Failed)
            throw new NotImplementedException("whoat");

        this.SetPublishTimeLag(result.XMLResult.Elements("tbl0").FirstOrDefault());
        this.AddFormView(result.XMLResult.Elements("tbl1").FirstOrDefault());
        this.AddPresentation(result.XMLResult.Elements("tbl2").DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault());

        this.SetBridge();
        this.InitializeGenerics();

    }
```

this.clientCache.DBService.FetchFromDB(...) method is calling another interface DBService that calls the method FetchFromDB, this fetchfromDb method goes to QSL server and retrieves a dataset.

Here is my test method.

```
public void TestResolveDate()
    {
        //using (ShimsContext.Create())
        //{
        //    Stat.Pi.Data.Fakes.ShimAuthenticator
        //}

        var appCache = new Fakes.StubIAppCache();
        appCache.DBServiceGet = DbServiceGet;


        ReportFORM formReport = new ReportForm(SeriesKey.SomeKey1, appCache);

        var series = new Fr Fakes.StubISeries();

        DateTime date = formReport.ResolveDate(series, DateTime.Now);


        //Assert.
    }
private IDBService DbServiceGet()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("@SeriesID", "50");

        var service = new Fakes.StubIDBService();
        service.FetchFromUnicornStringCommandTypeDictionaryOfStringObject = (s, type, arg3) => dict 
        return service;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the source code? That would really help any discussion.

Comment: Show us some code please...

Comment: I think the description is clear enough w/o code.

Comment: Calling a Db from an (abstract) base ctor seems like very tight coupling to me. I would consider some IoC here.

Answer (score 0):

1) The constructor should not be calling the database, as Henk Holterman says. This both increases the coupling and decreases the cohesion.

2) The design pattern you may be looking for is called a Factory Pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern - this separates construction, initialization and population. On the other hand, you may want to introduce a helper or handler class that deals with the persistence aspects of your object.

3) It is reasonable to put in a database access stub to perform testing, since refactoring your code may be outside your jurisdiction. However, personally, I would recommend introducing a persistence helper class to bind a newly created object to the database values.

Comment: can you advise on the way I would use Fakes to stub out the data access interface DBService and the method it calls FetchFromDB?

Comment: I'm trying to shim out the this.InitalizeSeries();
in the base constructor with using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                Series.Fakes.ShimSeriesBase.AllInstances.InitalizeSeries = () => { };
            } but the compiler says "Error 17 Delegate 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.FakesDelegates.Action<Series.SeriesBase>' does not take 0 arguments"